# Inserting/loading a javascript file after a div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to insert this ad code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php?type=banner&align=center&zone=1"></script>
```

right after

```
<div id="adminmenu"></div>
```

So that the output of the script will be displayed after the `adminmenu` div

Is there a way to do that using jquery? I tried `.insertAfter` but it only works on plain html.

Comment: does that link even have content?

Comment: Yes.. it displays random advertisements..

Comment: Can you post the code you originally tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render the content first in a hidden, temporary container:

```
<div class="temp">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php?type=banner&align=center&zone=1"></script>
</div>
```

then move the contents after it is rendered:

```
$('.temp').contents().appendTo(finalDestination)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a script is using `document.write()` to emit content, then you have to place the script in the place that you want the content to go.

If you control the script, then you can have the script not emit it's content by default and you can call a function in the script and pass a parent object that directs the script where it should put it's content (which it will not use `document.write()` to create).

The only other option is to place a div around the script, let it emit the content into that div and then move that container div to another location in the page after it runs.

```
<div id="ads">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/wp-content/plugins/oiopub-direct/js.php?type=banner&align=center&zone=1"></script>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ads").appendTo("#myFooter");
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to ask about jQuery.  jQuery is capable of inserting dynamically created content anywhere you want in the page.  You'd have to ask a more specific question for us to advise in more details.

Comment: I have a div naming `adminmenu` and i want to add the ad code just right after that div using jquery.. not appending its content.

Comment: @Ken, you need to tell us more about how the ad content is created before we can know how to help you.  Is it created inline with `document.write()` in its own container div?  You can put something after a div, but it's easier to put something in that div.  Why not make a div to put it into and use the code I've already provided you.